# Rolling Dice Probability Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image]

In this question do I have to find the probability of 1,2,3,4,5, and 6 individually or do I have to find their probability together? Also isn't this binomial distribution?

Comment: $12$ dice are rolled and you want two dice to get $1$, another two to get $2$ and so on. The key is to find is in how many ways you can get that.

Comment: Please use mathjax rather than images. This [guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good start.

Comment: and to your last question, yes it is binomial distribution

Comment: You have to find the probability  of the event described in the question.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding they are requesting to get exactly twice 1,2,3,4,5,6 in 12 rolls thus it is a multinomial, not a binomial

You have to calculate the probability of all the events like this one

$$\{1,3,5,1,2,2,4,6,5,3,4,6\}$$

Thus the requested probability is

$$\binom{12}{2,2,2,2,2,2}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{12}=\frac{12!}{2^6}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{12}\approx 0.34\%$$